# Google Docs won't convert my MS Word document -errors: "Can't convert password protected document"

Tags: google-docs

I have an MS Word document that I previously converted to Google Docs format without any trouble. Now, the Word document won't convert and Google displays an error message saying password protected documents can't be converted ... but the document isn't password protected.

I tried checking the Word document protection settings to ensure it wasn't protected and also copying and pasting the contents of the file into a new Word document but still had no luck.

Can anyone help me with what I need to do to be able to get Google Docs to convert my Word file?